# Checking if ID exists in collection containing multiple key values

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, relationship

I am creating an API with Laravel 5 and working on a following user feature.

I have a pivot table with user_id and user_following_id. When a GET request is made for a user, I do a relationship to return all the rows that match the user_id.

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower')->select(array('project_id', 'user_id'));
}
```

In my head, my aim was to just check if the user id (who is making the request) exists in the collection return from the relationship. However, for the relationship to work it returns two key values:

```
"followers":[{"project_id":23,"user_id":6}]}]
```

Is there a better way to do what I want?

I just want to check if an ID in the request exists in the pivot table where the user_id matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
public function followers(\Request $request) {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower')->select(array('project_id', 'user_id'))->where(['user_id', $request->user_id]);
}
```

be much easier?